# making line charts in the same graph from a matrix ROWS

Tags: r, graph, data-visualization, probability

I need to represent the ROWS of an R matrix M with line charts in the same graph
The columns are c(D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6) and for each column I have 30 probabilities

Comment: Use `matplot`.  If each row is one curve then you will need to transpose M first.

Comment: I got package ‘matplot’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)

Comment: It is a function in base R, not a package.  `?matplot`